# DRY code for sending email with SendGrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sendgrid

I have this code inside a post route:

The first one is to alert my when a user register in my site:

```
sendgrid.send({
        to:         "my@email.com",
        from:       "myother@email.com",
        subject:    "[ALERT] " + req.body.eventDate,
        html:       "SOME HTML",
    },
    function(err, json) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } 
        else {
            next();
        }
});
```

The next one is a confirmation email send to the new register member:

```
sendgrid.send({
        to:         req.body.email,
        from:       "my@email.com",
        subject:    "[CONFIRM] register" + req.body.eventDate,
        html:       "SOME HTML",
    },
    function(err, json) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } 
        else {
            next();
        }
});
```

Is working 100%, but this is not a good practice, there is so much duplicate. Can i DRY this? If so, howww??

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is not a question for SO, you could get your code dried at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function which can perform the operation of sending emails using `sendgrid` like this,

```
function sendEmail(options) {
  sendgrid.send(options,
    function(err, json) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } 
        else {
            next();
        }
  });
}
```

And then you can utilise above created function as following,

### For sending registration email

```
var registrationEmailOptions = {
        to:         "my@email.com",
        from:       "myother@email.com",
        subject:    "[ALERT] " + req.body.eventDate,
        html:       "SOME HTML",
}
sendEmail(registrationEmailOptions);
```

### For sending confirmation email.

```
var confirmationEmailOptions = {
        to:         req.body.email,
        from:       "my@email.com",
        subject:    "[CONFIRM] register" + req.body.eventDate,
        html:       "SOME HTML",
}
sendEmail(confirmationEmailOptions);
```

Comment: interesting! But can i use the same object name??

Comment: You can, but I will discourage you for doing that. Give option object meaningful name like `confirmationEmailOptions` and `registrationEmailOptions`. Check my edits

Comment: Kelsadita.. do you know why error is not will appear undefined inside the function??